# Blogs.sun.com is dead

Tags: discussion, broken-links

Oracle have killed off blogs.sun.com. You have a number of questions/answers that have links to blogs.sun.com that will need fixing.

[Here's the list](https://superuser.com/search?q=url:%22*blogs.sun.com*%22)

In general you just need to change the `http://blogs.sun.com` to `https://blogs.oracle.com`.

I have found (whilst working through the Serverfault list) that some new links are dead, presumably because the blog owner no longer works for Oracle so they need to be dealt with on a case by case basis.

Have fun.

Comment: Thanks for the fun.

Comment: The blog is dead, long live the blog.

Comment: If only HTTP supported some kind of redirect..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks for informing, most of them have been fixed now and I had remove links to few posts because they were dead as you'd mentioned above.

Comment: Sathya to the rescue!

Comment: well, @jokerdino did some of the work too :-)